# How to save file without overwrite excel file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, epplus

I am using `EPPlus.dll` in `Powershell` script to convert csv file to xlsx file, but I no have idea how to save file without overwrite existing data.

I have to generate new information from csv file to excel file, 
but I have others, manualy created tab which my script always overwrite.

Script looks like this:

```
$FileNameCSV = "$env:WORKSPACE/file.csv"
$FileNameExcel = "\\folder\file.xlsx "

$DLLPath = "D:\EPPlus.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DLLPath) | Out-Null

$Format = New-object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat
$Format.Delimiter = ","

$Format.TextQualifier = '"'
$Format.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$Format.SkipLinesBeginning = '0'
$Format.SkipLinesEnd = '1'

$TableStyle = [OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles]::Medium1

$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage 
$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("CM")

$null=$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText((Get-Item $FileNameCSV),$Format,$TableStyle,$true) 

$Worksheet.Cells[$Worksheet.Dimension.Address+1].AutoFitColumns()

$Worksheet.Column(3).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";

$ExcelPackage.SaveAs($FileNameExcel)

Write-Host "CSV File $FileNameCSV converted to Excel file $FileNameExcel"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the **existing** file named `$FileNameExcel` by passing the name to the constructor, probably like this:

```
  $ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage($FileNameExcel)
```

Then, add a new worksheet to this workbook, load the csv into this new worksheet the same way you do it currently, and save the workbook again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is working, but script still remove my existing data in the worksheet. I want to update only `CM` tab about new informations from csv file, but like I said before - I have `manually` created tabs, and I need them.

Comment: Sorry for double post, but you have right. Now it's working almost perfectly. Almost because when I open excel file a see the message like this:
`Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.`, but after removal feature like `AutoFilter from table` everything works fine! Probably would be nice have loops `if` to check whether a file exists.

Comment: @KamilK: EPPlus supports only a restricted number of Excel features, and some features probably not 100%. When you manually add data into a document, you can easily insert things not compatible EPPlus, so you have to be very careful what you are doing.

Comment: Maybe problem is related with code. I change only this:
`#$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
#$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("CM")`
on to:
`$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage($FileNameExcel)
$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1]`